# How to call function if date selected in datepicker is 20 years less than new date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to call different functions on range of years from `20 to 25`, `25 to 30`, `30 to 35`, and `35 to 40`. I know the function but I don't know how to put that function and select that range from a datepicker:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="birthdate">Date of Birth</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm mx-sm-3" id="birthdate" name="birthdate">
</div>
```

I've tried something like this in jQuery:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
  var startDate = $('#birthdate').val();
  var endDate = "1990-00-00";
  if (startDate > endDate) {
  }
});
```

But this is not correct way to do that. Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: What datepicker library are you using?

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI, you can use `$(this).datepicker('getDate')` to get the date as an object, then use `.getFullYear()` to get the year.

Comment: am using jquery ui datepicker

Comment: i want to do a function like if the user put his age and his age is in between the range of 1980 - 1984 or if his age is between 1985 - 1990 vise versa then i can do that function.

Comment: So `if (year >= 1980 && year <= 1984) { ... } else if (...) ...` and so on. What's the problem?

Comment: You should run the code in the datepicker's `onClose` method, not the `click` event on the input.

Comment: thank you so much @Barmar but can you tell me how can i compare that with the date user selected? like if he entered his birthdate and its year is between 1980 and 1984 as you wrote the code (thank you for that) so i can run the code than.

Comment: That is the date the user selected. `var year = $(this).datepicker("getDate").getFullYear();`

Comment: i tried your function but its not working. i inspect the page and it says that Cannot read property 'getFullYear'

Comment: i've just change $(this) to its id and working properly thank you so much mate love you